# React authentication/permissions and component rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jwt

I am building a project with a React frontend and .NET core backend.

One of the functions of the site is users can submit a form (an event/meetup) which goes to an admin user for approval. Once approved the event is posted on the website along with a list of others from other users.

I then want the user to be able to go to the event/meetup page and when they see their post they should see an edit button (only visible to them and admin) that allows them to modify their post.

This is just one feature of the project but all the others are very similar. User submits data, admin approves, gets posted to live website, user or admin can edit.

I am trying to figure out how to build in authentication/permissions.

I was looking at using JWT tokens.

I am new to React so trying to not use Redux if possible.

What do people suggest as the best way to tackle this?

How do I manage permissions and what parts of a component gets rendered?

Thank you.

Comment: this question doesn't have much to do with react. the answer is the same for every application.. user logs in, they get a token, the pass that token back and forth via ajax call to get permissions... then based on permissions conditionally render stuff

Answer (score 0):

Given the scope of the application that you have described, unless you have any unusual authentication requirements, I would simply consider using cookies to track the user.

A user can login via a HTTP request (AJAX or form post) then subsequent requests will include the authentication cookie ensuring that they're logged in.

Like @azium mentioned, this question is not particularly related to React but is standard authentication flow for any web application.